# jQueryUI Drag-n-Drop: clone not dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm playing with a little drag & drop ui, and I'm a bit stumped on the ***DROP***.
You can **[see the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/48nbs/)**.

**IMMEDIATE GOAL:**
I just need to find out how to get the `.draggable` span into either of the `.droppable` divs.
Presuming I'm on the right path with `append()`, how do I access the content of the clone?

**ULTIMATE GOALS:**
Ultimately, I'll need to add a way do delete items from the drop-zone divs and limit the `.textfield` input/div to accepting only a single drop (the `.textarea` input/div can accept an unlimited number of "payloads").

**CODE:**

```
/* html */
<table>
    <thead>    
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 494px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Company: activate to sort column descending">Company</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 66px;" aria-label="Contact">Contact</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 79px;" aria-label="&amp;nbsp;">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1 has_draggable_children">
                <span draggable="true" class="ui-draggable" data-companyid="0101" data-companyname="**BD">**BD</span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#4621">Contacts</a></td>
            <td><a href="#4621">Edit</a>
                <a href="#4621">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1 has_draggable_children">
                <span draggable="true" data-companyid="0202" data-companyname="0024" class="ui-draggable">0024</span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#4438">Contacts</a></td>
            <td><a href="#4438">Edit</a>
                <a href="#4438">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1 has_draggable_children">
                <span draggable="true" class="ui-draggable" data-companyid="0303" data-companyname="Acme, Inc.">Acme Anvil Corp</span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#4621">Contacts</a></td>
            <td><a href="#4621">Edit</a>
                <a href="#4621">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<section class="offset7" id="dragged-drop-zone" >
    <div class="look-like-input textfield droppable" contenteditable></div>
    <br />
    <div class="look-like-input textarea droppable" contenteditable></div>
</section>
```

.

```
/* js */
// DRAG
$('span[draggable]').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone"
});

// DROP
$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        //console.log(this);
        $(this).append($(ui.helper));
    }
});
```

Any and all help and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright  ...  got to the bottom of it.

The **`clone`** just doesn't seem to operate the way one would expect.
You end up having to use a custom function to package up your own clone into an object, and then pull it back out of your object in the `drop`.

You can **[see the working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/48nbs/4/)** on jsFiddle.
Here's what ended up working:

```
// Drag
$('span[draggable]').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: function() {
        var container = $('<div/>');
        var dragged = $(this);
        container.append(dragged.clone());
        return container;
    }
});

// Drop
$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.helper.children()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Should really be marked as a bug IMO... can't see why the jq team would have opted to do things this way, when clearly the object is cloned the moment it is dragged -- THAT being when it should be duplicated.